# Adobe Analytics not recording all prop updates

Tags: javascript, analytics, adobe-analytics

We have Adobe Analytics set up on our site, and we have a handful of share buttons. I've set up a direct call event to track a custom "Share" event whenever one is clicked, and to record the type of share (Facebook, Twitter, etc) in a prop so that we can categorize the shares and compare them

This works fine when the events come in with plenty of time between them, but when I try doing multiple shares back to back, only the last one is incrementing its property (Example: If I do a Twitter share, a Facebook share, and then a Pinterest share, I get 3 share events, but only Pinterest gets tracked as a share type instance)

Is there a way to keep these prop updates from getting conflated? Or is there a better way of subcategorizing a particular event?

sendEvent function:

```
sendEvent: function(analyticsEvent) {
    if(analyticsEvent.condition){
        if(analyticsEvent.props){
            for (var prop in analyticsEvent.props){
                if (analyticsEvent.props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    _satellite.setVar(prop,analyticsEvent.props[prop]);
                };
            }
        }
        _satellite.track(analyticsEvent.condition);
    }
}
```

Object I'm passing:

```
{
    condition: 'share',
    props: {shareType:'Twitter'}
}
```

DTM code:

```
var _shareType = _satellite.getVar('shareType');
s.prop123 = _shareType;
```

Comment: Code would help track down the issue.

Comment: @BrettAHale Added code

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have solved the issue. On the DTM side I'd only referenced the prop I was modifying in the custom code, not in the props section of the rule. I added `prop123 = "undefined"` there, and it looks like that fixed things somehow.